# Nvidia drivers don't let me log in

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have been playing some games on my Ubuntu 18.04 Thinkpad, and decided to switch to the nvidia drivers. I selected their drivers from software and updates, clicked apply, and rebooted. When I entered my password, it stayed on a black screen, and I couldn't move my mouse.

SOLUTIONS I TRIED:

- Changing the owner of ICEauthority (there is no Xauthority file in my home directory) to myself
- Installing DKMS

I would like to know the problem, as well as the solution, if there is any.

Thank you in advance.

**EXTRA INFORMATION:**

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic root=UUID=ffc39f60-f26b-49b3-bd48-838188f3395a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1

$ sudo lshw -C video         
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: GF108M [NVS 5400M]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       ressources: irq:34 mémoire:f0000000-f0ffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0000000-d1ffffff portE/S:6000(taille=128) mémoire:f1080000-f10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:33 mémoire:f1400000-f17fffff mémoire:e0000000-efffffff portE/S:7000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Did you remove "nomodeset" from your kernel boot line?  Please add the output of cat /proc/cmdline  and lshw -C video to your original post.

Comment: I have done that @ubfan1

Comment: You're still using the nouveau driver, Did your turn off secure boot?  That's incompatible with the Nvidia driver.  Check the files in /etc/modprobe.d for anything blacklisting the nvidia driver. Only nvidiafb is OK to blacklist.

Comment: Only nvidiafb is blacklisted, and how do I know if secure boot is on? @ubfan1

Comment: Check your machine's  UEFI Settings/BIOS for turning off secure boot.

Comment: Yep, secure boot is off @ubfan1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126863/discussion-between-adem-and-ubfan1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED :
I had to delete my `xorg.conf` file altogether. I don't know why it worked, but it did. I will edit this question to post why ASAP.